# Morgan showing GET message

Tags: node.js, reactjs, morgan

I am trying to make an application using reactjs, nodejs and mongoDB. I am facing an issue with `morgan` as it in consoling a message as `GET /images/icons/gear.png 404 160 - 1.746 ms` but i am not using any images in my project. Can you let me know where its coming from?

My network tab looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww2NF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are facing the same issue. The problem is not with `morgan` but with `json viewer pro` chrome extension. I disabled it and the problem is gone.